# restrict edition to one cell in row editorGrid

Tags: extjs, grid

in my editorGrid i have one column  with dateField editor , when the grid is rendred i set that field to non editable :

```
myColModel.setEditable(colIdex,false)
```

it will be editable after the value changed in other cell in the same row

```
myColModel.setEditable(colIdex,true)
```

the probleme is : all the cells in the column are editables

how can i do to make only the cell in the selected row editable

and many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'beforeedit' listener on the EditorGrid - you can inspect the field they are trying to edit. If the other field isn't set, return false to not allow them to edit that field.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can create conditional logic and hide the edit buttons based on the row model.

```
dataBound: function (){
       var grid = this;
       var trs = this.tbody.find('tr').each(function(){
         var item = grid.dataItem($(this));
         if( item.UnitPrice % 5 == 0) {
           $(this).find('.k-grid-edit,.k-grid-delete').hide();
         }
       });               
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way by just overriding the isCellEditable function. 
Check the below link.

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_Grid#Disable_editing_of_particular_rows.2C_columns.2C_etc